# Gluing maps on closed subspaces

Tags: general-topology

> $\textbf{PROBLEM}$
>
> Let $X$ and $W$ be topological spaces and suppose $W = A \cup B$. with
>   $A,B$ closed subsets of $W$. Suppose $f: A \to X$ and $g: B \to X$ are
>   continuous functions such that $f(w) = g(w) \; \; \forall w \in A \cap
>  B $. Then $h : W \to X $ defined by
>
> $$ h(w) = \left\{
>       \begin{array}{lr}
>        f(w) & : w  \in A\\
>        g(w) & : w \in B
>      \end{array}    \right. $$
>
> is well defined and continuous.

MY TRY:

To show continuity, suppose $C$ is closed in $X$, then

$$ h^{-1}(C) = h^{-1}(C) \cap W = h^{-1}(C) \cap (A \cup B) = (h^{-1}(C) \cap A) \cup (h^{-1}(C) \cap B)$$

Since in $A$, $h(w)=f(w)$, then $h^{-1}(C) \cap A = f^{-1}(C)$. Similarly, $h^{-1}(C) \cap B = g^{-1}(C)$. Therefore

$$ h^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C) $$

But $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $A$, and since $A$ is closed in $W$, then $f^{-1}(C)$ must be close in $W$. Similarly, $g^{-1}(C)$ must be closed in $W$. Since union of two closed sets is closed, then $f^{-1}(C)$ must be closed, and hence $h$ is continuous.

Is this correct? I feel like it is not necessary the hypothesis that $f = g$ on $A \cap B$. Can someone explain if I'm a correct? Also, How can I show the function is well-defined. I know this is trivial, but I just cant remember the definition of well defined.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis that $f(w)=g(w)$ for all $w\in A\cap B$ is needed in order for $h$ to be well-defined. Recall the definition of $h$:

$$h:W\to X:w\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(w),&\text{if }w\in A\\
g(w),&\text{if }w\in B\;.
\end{cases}$$

Suppose that $w\in A\cap B$; if $f(w)\ne g(w)$, this definition falls apart, since it says that $h(w)$ has to be two different points of $X$. Fortunately, we have the hypothesis that $f(w)=g(w)$ for every $w\in A\cap B$, so the two parts of the definition never disagree in the cases in which both apply.

Comment: Thanks Brian. MY argument showing it is continuous is correct? Can you give me some feedback?

Comment: @Don: Yes, everything else is correct. (Sorry: I should have said. In case I forget in the future, you can be pretty sure that if I do see a problem, I’ll mention it.)

Comment: Brian, Im still unsure how can I prove the function is well defined. Do I start with $h(a) \neq h(b)$ and then show $a \neq b$ ?

Comment: @Don: To show that it’s well-defined, you just have to show that the definition specifies exactly one value of $h(w)$ for each $w\in W$. The only values of $w$ for which this could possibly fail are those in $A\cap B$, since the definition of $h(w)$ has separate clauses for $w\in A$ and $h\in B$. However, you’re told that $f(w)=g(w)$ for all $w\in A\cap B$, so the two clauses give the same result whenever they both apply, and $h$ is therefore well-defined.